# Variable is not a type name error in c++

Tags: c++

I already have another inventory that is working just fine, but for some reason, my Paperclip inventory is not working. Both inventories are nearly identical except for their names.
But this inventory keeps telling me: Error E0757 variable "Paperclip" is not a type name. For the lines where the errors are marked, I have bolded the word "Paperclip".

I am not exactly sure how to solve this. I have googled around and the name is not the same as my header file. My header file is Inventory_Paperclip.The error says its only in my header file.

If someone could help point me in the right direction, or give me some pointers of where I am going wrong, it would be appreciated. Please let me know if you would like to see my main or anything else. 
I have posted my whole header file for Inventory_Paperclip below:

```
#ifndef Inventory_Paperclip
#define Inventory_Paperclip
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Base Class
struct Paperclip                                                    
{
    const int itemID;

    const char *name;

    Paperclip(int i, const char *n) : itemID(i), name(n) {}     

    virtual const char *typeName() const
    {
        return "";
    }

    virtual void print(ostream &out) const
    {
        out << typeName() << "(" << itemID << ")" << name << endl;
    }
};  // end of Base Class

typedef vector<Paperclip *> Paperclips;                             

ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const Paperclip &);              
ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const Paperclips &);             

//Only execute in a situation where the code is cout << Paperclip
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Paperclip &paperclip)           
{
    paperclip.print(out);                                       
    return out;
}

//Only execute in a situation where the code is cout << Paperclips
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Paperclips &paperclips)     
{
    for (Paperclips::const_iterator it = paperclips.begin(); it != paperclips.end(); it++)  
    {
        out << **it << endl;
    }

    return out;
}

//function to print out my Paperclip
void printPaperclip()
{
    Paperclips paperclips;
    paperclips.push_back(new Paperclip(1, "-- Paperclip"));
    cout << "Inventory Items: " << endl;
    cout << paperclips << endl;
    return;
}


#endif
```

Comment: The posted code compiles fine at https://ideone.com/yGBo97.

Comment: When asking about an error message. Always post the actual error you get (verbatim) *in* the question. And include info on your platform, compiler and compiler version. Also, please include a [mcve] rather than just a code snippet.

Comment: ...*and* also indicate *where* the error message is issued (line numbers generally don't work as in practice file won't be complete an SO doesn't show line numbers).

Comment: Sorry!   @JesperJuhl  I will be sure to include those next time. I am still a newbie at understanding the protocols for Stack Overflow

Comment: and @DietmarKühl ^

Comment: This should have compiled. It is unclear why / how it could be possibly failing the way you indicate.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add necessary information: the full and precise text of the error message and the line in the code it refers to.

Comment: @Candy It's not so much about "the protocols for Stack Overflow" as it is about *being able to answer your question*. Without the relevant info we can only guess. Think about it; could *you* answer your question based on just the info you give?  Well, neither can we.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm sorry... I don't understand?

Comment: itemID is initialized in the constructor here: `Paperclip(int i, const char *n) : itemID(i), name(n) {}`

Comment: @Candy your problem is in some part you are not showing us. I assume you have more than 1 file in your project but here you show what appears to be a single file and no int main().

Comment: my guess. In the other file(s) of the project you forgot to include this header

Comment: Well I am trying to add this file into my main, and add it to my code. It is a text based game, and this is an inventory to store the paperclip. I wanted to call it in my main as printPaperclip();

Comment: I have another inventory called Pin and that one works just fine, and I am able to call and use it in my main as printPin();

Comment: I don't think there is any way for us to help with this problem.

Comment: Its just that everytime I want to use my Paperclip function, it brings errors back to the header saying that paperclip is not a name type. I have my headers for paperclip declared in the different files it belongs in. I am using the right spelling, I have checked. I just don't know why the header file keeps saying that. My main has no issue with it, if you would like I can pull it up. But my main is just an if statement saying if the user has said a certain word then it pulls up my printPaperclip function which is all defined in my header file, Inventory_Paperclip

Comment: Maybe you have some circular include path. Remember that 2 headers should not include each other.

Comment: Yes I checked... no I do not see it. It's fine, I'll try to figure it out. Thank you for trying everyone!

Comment: My advice is to create a new project with the exact code that is in the first comment (from @RSahu) since we know that compiles. After getting this to build in your IDE continue adding your additional code until you break it.